# TypeScript errors using Multer in Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, multer

```js
import multer, { FileFilterCallback } from "multer";
import sharp from "sharp";
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

const multerStorage = multer.memoryStorage();

const multerFilter = (
  req: Request,
  file: Express.Multer.File,
  cb: FileFilterCallback
) => {
  if (file.mimetype.startsWith("image")) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error("Not an image! Please upload only images."), false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({ storage: multerStorage, fileFilter: multerFilter });

export const uploadRecipeImages = upload.array("images", 6);

export const resizeRecipeImages = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  if (!req.files?.images) return next();

  req.body.images = [];

  await Promise.all(
    req.files.images.map(async (file, index) => {
      const filename = `recipe-${req.params.id}-${Date.now()}-${
        index + 1
      }.jpeg`;

      await sharp(file.buffer)
        .resize(1024, 1024)
        .toFormat("jpeg")
        .jpeg({ quality: 90 })
        .toFile(`public/img/recipes/${filename}`);

      req.body.images.push(filename);
    })
  );

  next();
};
```

I'm using multer package in an express app. I get two TypeScript errors:

1. *Argument of type 'Error' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.ts(2345)* in `cb(new Error("Not an image! Please upload only images."), false);`
2. *Property 'images' does not exist on type '{ [fieldname: string]: File[]; } | File[]'.
   Property 'images' does not exist on type 'File[]'.ts(2339)* in `if (!req.files?.images) return next();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [filefilter](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#filefilter) documentation, the `cb` can only be used below ways:

```
function fileFilter (req, file, cb) {

  // The function should call `cb` with a boolean
  // to indicate if the file should be accepted

  // To reject this file pass `false`, like so:
  cb(null, false)

  // To accept the file pass `true`, like so:
  cb(null, true)

  // You can always pass an error if something goes wrong:
  cb(new Error('I don\'t have a clue!'))

}
```

And, we can find the `FileFilterCallback`  interface:

```
/**
 * a function to control which files should be uploaded and which should be skipped
 * pass a boolean to indicate if the file should be accepted
 * pass an error if something goes wrong
 */
interface FileFilterCallback {
    (error: Error): void;
    (error: null, acceptFile: boolean): void;
}
```

Your code `cb(new Error("Not an image! Please upload only images."), false);` does not match any interface. That's why you got the error.

So you can call the `cb` function like `cb(new Error("Not an image! Please upload only images."));`  to match the `(error: Error): void;` interface.

[`.array(fieldname[, maxCount])`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#arrayfieldname-maxcount)

> Accept an array of files, all with the name fieldname. Optionally error out if more than maxCount files are uploaded. The array of files will be stored in `req.files`.

The images will be stored in `req.files`.

So it should be:

```js
if (!req.files) return next();
```

package versions:

```json
"multer": "^1.4.4",
"@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
```